# Target children <ul> via CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a comment design setup like this:

```
<div class="comment">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <ul><li>
        <div class="comment">
            <p>Hello child</p>
            <ul><li>
                <div class="comment">
                    <p>Hello child 2</p>
                    <ul>...</ul>
                </div>
            </li></ul>
        </div>
    </li></ul>
</div>
```

Is it possible to target the 2nd `<ul>` child?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3seagmLv/) if needed.

Comment: `#comment > ul > li`

Comment: @vihan1086 I was asking, is it possible to target the **second** child ul...

Comment: @HenrickPetterson Ah, `.comment:first-child > ul > li > div > ul > li`

Comment: Can you edit your question to indicate the exact element you wish to target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, with no other HTML markup:

```
body > .comment > ul > li > div > ul > li {background: red}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3seagmLv/1/

If there is in real any parent above first `.comment`, it will be instead of `body`

```
parent > .comment > ul > li > div > ul > li {background: red}
```

EDIT to comment below:

To select 2nd and each other ULs,

```
body > .comment > ul > li > div ul {background: red}
```

Comment: Interesting, is it possible to target the second ul child **and all other** that comes after it?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson: sure, everything is possible. I've updated my answer to target 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc. ULs.

Comment: What is the purpose of `body`? What is the purpose of `div`? What is the purpose of the last `li`, since `color` is an inherited property?

Comment: @torazaburo: 1. `body` has be there to target the first one `.comment` element without changes in HTML and the possibly widest browsers support (instead of `first-of-type` etc.). 2. `div` in first two codes from the same reason as 1), in 3rd code snippet isn't necessary but isn't mistake. 3. doesn't matter if UL or LI. Color is inherited, but we speak about background which isn't (LI because UL could have padding etc.). You voted down, it's your choice but I'm not sure why. Ego reasons probably. If you think you are able to do it better (point 1), please post your code. Really appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use:

```
ul ul {
 /* Your styling */
}
```

Comment: It takes 2nd and each other nested ULs, not just the second one.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to select in nested layout like that, you can use `ul ul`:

```css
ul ul { /* set styles */ }
```

That will select all `ul` elements nested inside (at least) another `ul`.

```css
ul ul {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <ul><li>
    <div class="comment">
      <p>Hello child 1</p>
      <ul><li>
        <div class="comment">
          <p>Hello child 2</p>
          <ul><li>
            <div class="comment">
              <p>Hello child 3</p>
              <ul><li>
                <div class="comment">
                  <p>Hello child 4</p>
                </div>
              </li></ul>
            </div>
          </li></ul>
        </div>
      </li></ul>
    </div>
  </li></ul>
</div>
```

If you only want to affect the `ul` elements nested in exactly one `ul`,

```css
ul ul    { /* set styles   */ }
ul ul ul { /* unset styles */ }
```

```css
ul ul {
    border: 1px solid;
}
ul ul ul {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <ul><li>
    <div class="comment">
      <p>Hello child 1</p>
      <ul><li>
        <div class="comment">
          <p>Hello child 2</p>
          <ul><li>
            <div class="comment">
              <p>Hello child 3</p>
              <ul><li>
                <div class="comment">
                  <p>Hello child 4</p>
                </div>
              </li></ul>
            </div>
          </li></ul>
        </div>
      </li></ul>
    </div>
  </li></ul>
</div>
```

Note this can be generalized. For example, you can affect all `ul` nested in exactly 1 or 2 `ul` elements:

```css
ul ul       { /* set styles   */ }
ul ul ul ul { /* unset styles */ }
```

```css
ul ul {
    border: 1px solid;
}
ul ul ul ul {
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <p>Hello</p>
  <ul><li>
    <div class="comment">
      <p>Hello child 1</p>
      <ul><li>
        <div class="comment">
          <p>Hello child 2</p>
          <ul><li>
            <div class="comment">
              <p>Hello child 3</p>
              <ul><li>
                <div class="comment">
                  <p>Hello child 4</p>
                </div>
              </li></ul>
            </div>
          </li></ul>
        </div>
      </li></ul>
    </div>
  </li></ul>
</div>
```